# Counting blocks in a specific location (autolisp)

Tags: autocad, autolisp

So I'm making a simple function in autolisp to count the number of a specific block in a drawing, and it looks like this:

```
(defun c:contarblocos()
    (setq ss (ssget "x" ' ((0. "INSERT") (2. "Nome do bloco"))))
    (setq count (sslength ss))
    (alert(strcat "Total de blocos no desenho: " (itoa count)))
)
```

Now, what I really want is to count the number of blocks in a specific area, defined by the user. In other words, the user will call the function, and then the function will ask for a specific area, where it will look for the specific block and count them, not counting any blocks from outside the selected area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the `x` mode string of the [`ssget`](http://lee-mac.com/ssget.html) function (which searches the entire drawing database for all entities which fulfil the criteria of the filter list argument), simply omit this argument to permit the user to make a selection using any valid selection method, e.g.:

```
(defun c:contarblocos ( / sel )
    (if (setq sel (ssget '((0 . "INSERT") (2 . "Nome do bloco"))))
        (alert (strcat "Total de blocos no desenho: " (itoa (sslength sel))))
    )
    (princ)
)
```

There are a few other issues with your current code:

- Always declare the variables whose scope is local to your function: in my above example, you will note that the `sel` symbol is declared in the variable list within the `defun` expression. For more information on why this is important, you may wish to refer to my tutorial [here](http://lee-mac.com/localising.html).
- You should test whether `ssget` returns a valid selection set before calling the `sslength` function to obtain the number of items in the set, since `(sslength nil)` will error. You will see that I use an `if` statement in my code to accomplish this.
- The `ssget` filter list argument should be an association list of dotted pairs, and as such, there should be a space between the `key` and the `value` in each list item, hence this:

  ```
  (0. "INSERT")
  ```

  Should become:

  ```
  (0 . "INSERT")
  ```
- You should include a final `(princ)` or `(prin1)` expression within the `defun` expression so that the function returns a null symbol to the command line, rather than returning the value returned by the last evaluated expression (i.e. the `alert` expression, which will return `nil`). Including a `(princ)` expression per my example will ensure that the function exits 'cleanly'.